# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:drawable' with parameter type android.graphics.drawable.Drawable on android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm making a binding adapter where a I can set color filter to a drawable.

So I have these lines of code in java class

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"drawable", "filterColor"}, requireAll= true)
public static void setColorFilterToDrawable(View view, int drawableInt, @ColorRes int color){
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(),drawableInt);
    drawable.setColorFilter(new
            PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(), color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    view.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

In XML, I use it like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/textCircle"
    android:drawable="@{@drawable/background_circle}"
    app:colorFilter="@{@color/primaryDark}"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="X"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:onClick="@{viewModel::deletePhoto}" />
```

Comment: there is no `android:drawable` attribute for `TextView`. That's why there is no setter. What are you trying to use that drawable for?

Comment: im putting a circular drawable in it

Comment: ok, and where should it show?

Comment: is should be the background of the textview

Comment: If you want to have a **background**, then why you don't use `android:background` attribute? isn't it obvious?

Comment: yes im already doing that , the function of the binding adapter that I created was to put a color filter to the circular drawable

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: well i think that's it , there's no android:drawable attribute for TextView but i didn't test it yet.

Comment: that's what I said - there is no such attribute for TextView.

Comment: yeah i know, I just quoted you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:drawable` does not exist for `TextView`. Judging from your `@BindingAdapter` you're expecting a value set to `app:drawable`.

Additionally `@drawable` and `@color` expand to a drawable and a color integer. So your `@BindingAdapter` should implement the following interface instead.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"drawable", "filterColor"}, requireAll= true)
public static void setColorFilterToDrawable(View view, Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int color){
    drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    view.setBackground(drawable);
}
```